# Detect specific frequency in audio file using R

Tags: r, audio, pitch-detection

I have an audio recording wav file of a cricket chirping, every so often a chirp occurs for ~ 0.01 seconds at about 20kHz. I would like to use R to detect at what times during the recording the specific frequency (20kHz) occurs/starts.

Wave Object

```
Number of Samples:      4041625
Duration (seconds):     91.65
Samplingrate (Hertz):   44100
Channels (Mono/Stereo): Mono
PCM (integer format):   TRUE
Bit (8/16/24/32/64):    16
```

Comment: That's an interesting problem to tackle. It would be good if you could host the file somewhere to let others try to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe [`dfreq`](http://rug.mnhn.fr/seewave/) from the `seewave` package is what you're after. The method returns the dominant frequency (the one with the highest amplitude) over time (in seconds). Here's an exampleof how you could get that information:

```r
library(tuneR)
library(seewave)

# Read audio file
crickets <- readWave("~/crickets.wav")

# Get dominant frequency
d <- dfreq(crickets, plot = FALSE)

head(d)

#               x        y
# [1,] 0.00000000 0.000000
# [2,] 0.02332295 0.000000
# [3,] 0.04664589 0.000000
# [4,] 0.06996884 0.000000
# [5,] 0.09329179 0.000000
# [6,] 0.11661474 2.583984
```

Answer (score 1):

As @anddt says, `dfreq` is a good option although it often requires some tuning of various parameters such as `threshold` and `wl`. Here's a toy example with some made up data containing noise.

```
library(seewave)
library(tuneR)

chirp = sine(freq = 20000, duration = 0.01, xunit = 'time')
silence_0.2 = silence(duration = 0.2, xunit = 'time')
silence_0.1 = silence(duration = 0.1, xunit = 'time')
noise_0.2 = noise(kind='pink', duration=0.2, xunit = 'time')
noise_0.1 = noise(kind='pink', duration=0.1, xunit = 'time')
signal = bind(silence_0.2, chirp, noise_0.1, silence_0.2, chirp, silence_0.1, noise_0.2, chirp, noise_0.2, silence_0.2)

# threshold removes noise, wl is the window length of the fourier transform, smaller 
# values give more accuracy for time but noise gets more troublesome
peaks = data.frame(dfreq(signal, threshold = 10, wl = 128, plot=F))
peaks[is.na(peaks)] = 0
names(peaks) = c('time', 'frequency')
peaks$frequency[peaks$frequency < 19.9 | peaks$frequency > 20.1] = 0

startindices = which(diff(peaks$frequency) > 19)
endindices = which(diff(peaks$frequency) < -19)
starttimes = peaks[startindices, 1]
endtimes = peaks[endindices, 1]

plot(signal, col='grey')
abline(v = starttimes, col='green')
abline(v = endtimes, col='red')
```

The result looks like this. Green vertical lines for the starts, and red vertical lines for the ends of chirps.

[image]